# Get variable from a page to index page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a variable called `$total` in a page called `page-pants.php`,
i need to echo the variable called `$total` in `index.php` page.
how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing to use is a non expiring transient.  Set your `$total` with the following code in your `page-pants.php` file.  I am assuming that the $total value is changing each time you visit the pants page.

```
delete_transient( 'pants_total' );
// Save $total as the transient pants_total
set_transient( 'pants_total', $total );
```

Then you can access the $total anywhere in your WordPress site with the following

```
$total = get_transient( 'pants_total' );
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define and set that in your functions.php and use that in everywhere that you need.

For example:

```
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');

function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }

    $_SESSION['myKey'] = "Some data I need later";
}

function myEndSession() {
    session_destroy ();
}
```

And show that in each theme file that you need:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['myKey'])) {
    $value = $_SESSION['myKey'];
} else {
    $value = '';
}
echo $value;
```